# Ruby on Rails - database configuration does not specify adapter production

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, rake, passenger

I'm trying to setup my application online using Passenger, Apache, and MySQL but when I run this command I get the following error

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV='production'

rake aborted!
database configuration does not specify adapter
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Have you tried to specify `socket: path/to/socket/mysql.sock` for the development environment?

Comment: just tried it and i got this error(<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context

Comment: Which host are you using? Usually when it comes to deployment it is enough to specify `host: hostname`, because mysql will know where to find the socket.

Comment: I have the site hosted on a rakespace cloud server and i can get a blank app installed and the default index page to show up but as soon as i try and connect to the database i get these errors.

Comment: Does your configuration specify an adapter? We can't see it-perhaps including the configuration in question would be helpful?!